# Is it really necessary to create a job for each video file in Amazon Elastic Transcoder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm currently investigating how we can use AWS Elastic Transcoder to transcode a couple of thousand video's we have in an S3 bucket, but it seems that I need to create a job by hand for each individual video file.

I'm probably overlooking the obvious but after searching the documentation I can only conclude that this is the only option. Is there someone who can tell me I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get a list of file names quite easily.  Automation will take a bit of programming.  I have done this through ruby a while ago.  But the links below should get you on the proper path.

These links should get you in the right direction:

http://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-cli--create.html

http://aws.amazon.com/cli/

http://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/faqs/

Q: What tools and libraries work with Amazon Elastic Transcoder?

Amazon Elastic Transcoder uses a JSON API, and we provide SDKs for Python, Node.js, Java, .NET, PHP, and Ruby. The new AWS Command Line Interface also supports Amazon Elastic Transcoder. You can see a full list of our SDKs here.